# How can I build binutils for Android?

Tags: android-ndk, binutils

I am building binutils for my x86 Android(Remix OS).
I am using NDK toolchain.

I built 'make' successfully with using this configure command:

```
./configure --host=x86_64-linux-android --prefix=/home/newnis/remixBin/
```

I tried same thing on binutils. But it fails with these messages:

```
Invalid configuration `x86_64-linux-android': machine `x86_64-linux' not recognized
Invalid configuration `x86_64-linux-android': machine `x86_64-linux' not recognized
Unrecognized host system name x86_64-linux-android.
```

I also tried using '--build' instead of '--host'. But it also fails.

```
Configuring for a x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu host.
Invalid configuration `x86_64-linux-android': machine `x86_64-linux' not recognized
Unrecognized build system name x86_64-linux-android.
```

I cannot build binutils for Android?

Comment: binutils-like tools should be available with the NDK. Check `..\ndk-bundle\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it...

Problem was I was trying with binutils-2.9 which built in 1998.
I tried latest one and I configured with no problem.